# How n_distinct() function from dplyr works internally?

Tags: r, dplyr

I like dplyr package available in R as it has a clear and easy syntax. I am in the retail domain and very often use n_distinct() function from the same package. I want to know-how the n_distinct() function works internally to calculate the length of unique elements?

I have tried to do it with typing the name of the function in R-console. It gives me the following output:

```
>n_distinct()
function (..., na.rm = FALSE) 
{
    n_distinct_multi(list(...), na.rm)
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000766eee8>
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

It seems that it is using n_distinct_multi() function inside. But I am not getting any code for this function:

```
>n_distinct_multi
Error: object 'n_distinct_multi' not found
> dplyr:: n_distinct_multi
Error: 'n_distinct_multi' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'
>? n_distinct_multi
No documentation for ‘n_distinct_multi’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??n_distinct_multi’
```

Please tell me how to get what it is doing internally?

Comment: It's an internal function not explicitly exported by the `dplyr` package, so to access you need to use `:::`, like `dplyr:::n_distinct_multi`.

Comment: Try `getAnywhere('n_distinct_multi')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @caldwellst & @Rui Barradas for your comments, both of your solutions are working fine. I am posting this answer to help someone who doesn't have an idea about internal functions in R. 
"Internal functions can be used by other functions of the same package, but are not available to directly call from R-console. To call an internal function you should use ::: operator along with the package name."

For e.g. 
n_distinct_multi() is an internal function from dplyr package which is called by n_distinct() function to find the length of unique values in a given vector.

To be clear

```
> library(dplyr)
> n_distinct
function (..., na.rm = FALSE) 
{
    n_distinct_multi(list(...), na.rm)
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000766eee8>
<environment: namespace:dplyr>

> n_distinct_multi
Error: object 'n_distinct_multi' not found

> dplyr:::n_distinct_multi
function (variables, na_rm = FALSE) 
{
    .Call(`_dplyr_n_distinct_multi`, variables, na_rm)
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000943eda8>
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

where _dplyr_n_distinct_multi() is a compiled function from C/C++ library. You can use n_distinct_multi() function to find the length of unique values of a vector like this:

```
> dplyr:::n_distinct_multi(list(c(1:10,10)))
[1] 10
```

You can also use getAnywhere() to view the code for an internal function.

```
> library(dplyr)
> getAnywhere('n_distinct_multi')
A single object matching ‘n_distinct_multi’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:dplyr
with value

function (variables, na_rm = FALSE) 
{
    .Call(`_dplyr_n_distinct_multi`, variables, na_rm)
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000943eda8>
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```